# Angular 4+ Dependency Injection - Getting the closest host component out of more possibilities

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular5

i want to inject a host component to its child component using Dependency Injection.

My problem right now is, that the markup is dynamic and there are more than one possible host components. Further is only the closest host components needed.
What is the best way to get the closest host component ?

Therefore i prepared a stackblitz-app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mpnas

This is an example of the HTML Markup

```
<comp-a [name]="'Lorem'">
    <comp-b [name]="'ipsum'">
        <comp-c [name]="'dolor'">
            <comp-b [name]="'sit'">
                <div class="someDivClass">
                    <hello></hello>
                </div>
            </comp-b>
        </comp-c>
    </comp-b>
</comp-a>
```

And the component:

```
import { Component, Input, Optional, Host, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompA } from './comp-a/comp-a.component';
import { CompB } from './comp-b/comp-b.component';
import { CompC } from './comp-c/comp-c.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    @Optional() @Host() private a: CompA,
    @Optional() @Host() private b: CompB,
    @Optional() @Host() private c: CompC,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.a.name);
    console.log(this.b.name);
    console.log(this.c.name);

    // what Component is the closest Host Element

  }
}
```

best regards...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a clean way to get this, but you can achieve your goal with `viewContainerRef` element.

Import it from here:

`import { ViewContainerRef  } from '@angular/core';`

Load it to your constructor:

```
onstructor(
    @Optional() @Host() private a: CompA,
    @Optional() @Host() private b: CompB,
    @Optional() @Host() private c: CompC,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  )
```

the `viewContainerRef` contains nodes in the same ordering in which the hosts are piled on eachother.

`this.viewContainerRef._view.nodes[last].renderElement` is the component that occurs the in the last row; holding the name: `this.viewContainerRef._view.nodes[i].componentView.component.name`

Go [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3szqnz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) open the console and see the log.

Comment: This works fine for the last component. But it should work for any Component.

Comment: @dindunuffin yea, and you didn't intend to say "last" by the word "closest" ? btw, this does print all parent hosts hierarchically.